# ITfoxtec BindCOnfig error - please see image

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

[image]

I am using the latest Library from Nuget, do I need to get the latest from GitHub?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension method is in the `ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore` Nuget package in a namespace with the same name.

The [code](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore/Extensions/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it. The newest NuGet release is 3/24/22. BindConfig support was added later on 6/1/22. So if you want to use the version that's in NuGet, just select the next oldest version of the test app in GitHub to get the code that doesn't use BindConfig. For the TestWebAppCore Startup.cs file it's https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/d31f7a1b1ff9251810a4fcef8ac2dc920e2a94ef/test/TestWebAppCore/Startup.cs