# 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'BindConfig' and no accessible extension method 'BindConfig'

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Please provide the steps to resolve the BindConfig error for ITfoxTec.

[image]

I have checked this link but not able to understand the solution for this issue.

[ITfoxtec BindCOnfig error - please see image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73338664/itfoxtec-bindconfig-error-please-see-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BindConfig` functionality is currently only release in beta versions, I'm afraid. It will soon be released in a final release.

At this time you can safely use version 4.8.3-beta4.